# Find matrix $A$ such that $A^2=B$ and $A^3=C$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given 
B=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}

and C=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}
Find matrice $A$ such that $A^2=B$ and $A^3=C$.

My attempt(seems correct) I was thinking of adjacency matrix of a directed graph on 5 vertices. Here $A^3=C$ means there is 1 path of length 3 from 1to 4 and $A^2=B$ means there is 1 path of length 2 from vertex 1 to 3, 1 to 5 and 2 to 4. From that I deduced that what the original graph look like and get that A=  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 &0 &0& 1& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}

Comment: What have you tried? Please add your attempts in the question (not in the comments), that way it is easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: Note that in general there may not exist a matrix $A$ with $A^2=B$ and $A^3=C$. Take $B=0$ and $C=I_n$, for example.

Comment: Hint: In $AB = C$ and $BA = C$, treat $A$ as a linear transformation on $B$.  You have two different interpretations of $L_A: B\mapsto C$.  Can you continue?

Comment: I think your attempt is a very good one already.  TBH, I think it works better than the accepted answer (if you want to find just one matrix $A$, not all possible $A$, of course).  I was thinking about this approach right away when I saw the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so we know $A^2=B$ and $A^3=C$. From this we get that $AB=C$

so:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4&a_5\\
b_1&b_2&b_3&b_4&b_5\\
c_1&c_2&c_3&c_4&c_5\\
d_1&d_2&d_3&d_4&d_5\\
e_1&e_2&e_3&e_4&e_5
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\ 0 &0 &0& 0& 0\\
  \end{bmatrix}$$
now you could multiply this out and solve the simultaneous equations you get

Comment: The first two columns of $A$ can be found by inspection. Recall that right-multiplying by the $j$th column of the identity picks out the $j$th column of the matrix.